# C++ : Ambiguous Behavior of Ternary Operator

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, conditional-operator

I tried and tested the following code to understand the behavior of ternary operator. But it is only making things complicated for me.
The code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(bool a, bool b, bool c) {
    int x, y, z, w;
    cout << (a ? (b ? x = 5 + b : y = 10 + b) : (c ? z = 15 + c : w = 20 + c)) << endl;
    cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << " " << w << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!\n";
    print(false, false, false);
    print(false, false, true);
    print(false, true, false);
    print(false, true, true);
    print(true, false, false);
    print(true, false, true);
    print(true, true, false);
    print(true, true, true);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output of this is as follows:

```
Hello world!
20
0 0 0 20
16
0 0 16 20
20
0 0 16 20
16
0 0 16 20
10
0 10 16 20
10
0 10 16 20
6
6 10 16 20
6
6 10 16 20
```

It doesn't look like this is following a procedure similar to the standard if-else procedure. Any guesses?

Edit: Initializing the variables to some random integers (say -1) resolved the issue. Moreover, it somehow reused the variable values in subsequent calls.

Comment: Which line in particular are you confused by?  What did you expect to get instead, and why?

Comment: Also you are not initializing your variables

Comment: I would not use this code as a tutorial at all. Not only is it hard to read it's loaded with bugs.

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing uninitialized variables. Each `print` call only initializes one of `x`, `y`, `z` and `w`, but prints all four.

Comment: If the point of confusion is the output of the line `cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << " " << w << endl;`, then drop that line or initialize your variables. The line that demonstrates the behavior of the ternary operator is the one containing the ternary operators.

Comment: *It doesn't look like this is following a procedure similar to the standard if-else procedure.*  It looks like it is following a procedure similar to the standard if-else procedure.  Try rewriting the ternary into an if-else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have strange results because you arn't initializing the x, y, and z variables.
The old value is being resused.
Init them with 0 and you'll get different results

Comment: "The old value is being reused." Which old value? Anyway, anything may happen for UB.

Comment: As you say it is an UB. I suspect that subsequent calls to the function are reusing the old memory used for x, y, z and w in the new call. Hence the output shows an output like the one you get when the variables are static.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I tried initializing all the variables to -1 and now the results are as expected. Glad to know I should initialize variables beforehand.